# How to send email in background in PHP?

Tags: php, email

I have a user registering form. When user registers, all the data entered will be saved in database and confirmation email will be sent to user. But  I do not want the user to wait for the email sending. So I want it sent in the background. Even if the user goes to another page, the task must be running in the background.

I tried [this article](http://foreigngods.com/blog/2013/03/14/10/run-a-php-script-in-the-background-after-a-form-has-been-submitted/), but it is not working. I also do not want to use database for that as well. How can I achieve it?

Comment: If the user does not need the email immediately, you could use a `cron` job (e.g. poll the system every 5 minutes), or you would have to set up some `Gearman` server (a bit of an overload for only sending emails).

Comment: Thank u for suggestion. I am trying to use Gearman. I am installing environment for PECL using command line. But I cant install it . Please how to install it for windows. I used this command. "pecl install channel://pecl.php.net/gearman-1.1.2" and "pecl install gearman" . Both not working. I am using Codeigniter for my project.

Answer (score 0):

```
**USE THIS CODE ON BOTTOM OF PAGE**

function partialResponse()
            {
                $response=array();
                ignore_user_abort(true);
                ob_start();
                echo json_encode($response);
                header("Status: 200");
                header($_SERVER["SERVER_PROTOCOL"] . " 200 Ok");
                header("Content-Type: application/json");
                header('Content-Length: '.ob_get_length());
                ob_end_flush();
                ob_flush();
                flush();
            }

AFTER THAT CALL THIS FUNCTION BEFORE SENDING THE EMAIL

INSIDE CORE PHP partialResponse() OR INSIDE THE $this->partialResponse()
```

EXAMPLE:

partialResponse();
sendEmail();

$this->partialResponse();
$this->email->send();